# Xamarin Forms: Grid of images has too much space between elements row-wise

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid with 2 columns intended to host images.

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Grid
          x:Name="gridLayout"
          RowSpacing="5"
          VerticalOptions="Start">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

Images are added programatically because i don't know the amount prior of execution. An Image is declared like this

```
Image image = new Image
                {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(filepath)),
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                };
```

The result is this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZpHv.png)

My intention is to narrow this vertical space between the images.

Comment: are you setting a height on the Rows as you add them?

Comment: I think it is because of image aspect you are seeing the gaps. Try setting the `Aspect` to fill to check if it has to do with it

Comment: @Jason no. When I add them I only specify row and column number.

Comment: @zafar If I change it to Fill, this happens [link](https://imgur.com/rDpZGT6). I am going for a look like in the question's Screenshot, only without the gaps.

Comment: you need to add RowDefinitions to define the height of your rows

Comment: @ȘtefanTeodor yes, that is how it is suppose to look like. You either need to set the `RowHeight` matching the Image's Aspect Ratio, so that when you set the aspect to fill, the image doesn't look stretched. Or you need to set the `Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill` to avoid stretching, but then you will end up clipping some portion of the image, if the cell dimensions in the grid does not match with the image aspect ratio

Comment: make RowSpacing=0 and use top and bottom padding of 2.5 on each image?

Comment: @zafar I ended up adjusting the `HeightRequest` of the Image to match the Image's Aspect Ratio (like you suggested to do with `RowHeight` ) and kept the `Aspect.AspectFit` . I am more that satisfied with the [result](https://imgur.com/Qgr3NHX). Thank you for your input!

Comment: OK then I am gonna post that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional vertical spacing is not due to the `Grid`'s `RowSpacing`, but it is due to the padding introduced by the image `AspectRatio`. Once the `Row`'s `Height` and `Column`'s width are set to match with `Image`'s aspect ratio and `AspectRatio` Property on the Image is set to `Aspect.Fill` the additional padding should go away